# MVC4 Google Crawable Single Page App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

Is there a clean way to make my Single Page Application crawable for google. The only solution that i've in my mind is to use the index action to return the html that i get with the webbrowsercontrol. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use asp.net single page application check link for detail

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: Seems to make no difference to me.